# I can't stand much more of this

Tags: parts-of-speech, quantifiers

Can we use 'adverb' before pronoun?

As we know adverbs are normally used to modify 'other adverbs' , 'verbs', and 'adjectives'. e.g (I'm feeling a lot better today.)

I consider 'a lot and 'much' as **adverbs** and 'more' as **pronoun** in the following. Is my analysis OK?

I earn *a lot* **more** than my sister does.

I have *a lot* **more** in common with my friends than my family.

I can't stand *much* **more** of this.

Comment: I suggest you post this over on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).  It's splitting hairs whether some part of speech is an adverb or an adjective, what's important is how to use it effectively in communication.  Aside from your technical question, is there any reason why you are having trouble using this idiom?

Comment: more is not a pronoun. A pronoun is a word that stands for another word. More does not stand for another word. I earn a lot more=Subject [I] + Verb [earn] + a lot [adverb] + more [adjective]. Perhaps you should brush up on pronouns.

Comment: If *more* can't be a pronoun (in traditional grammar), a lot of dictionaries must label the part of speech of *more* wrong. Let's take Oxford Dictionaries, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/more; *more* in an example (*Tell me more.*) is clearly marked as pronoun.

Comment: I earn MORE [money] than my sister does. MORE is not a pronoun there. It's an adjective. More does not stand for pronoun in this example.

Comment: @Lambie You'll have to contend with lots of dictionaries e.g. the OED which has: "**B.** _pron._ **I.** Something greater. **1.** As a comparative corresponding to much: something that is more." It's a determinative, too, and there's squabbling here and there, but in things like _"It costs more_" it's a pronoun.

Comment: For me, it is an adjective as the noun is implied. earned more [money]. Clearly an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

*More* is a *indefinite pronoun* in one of your examples, but *much* and *a lot* are not adverbs here.

In:

> I can't stand much more of this.

..."Much" is not an adverb. It is a *determinative,* and it in turn modifies the determinative *more.* This means that *much more* is a *noun phrase* and it quantifies the pronoun *this* which is the object of the preposition in the comparative phrase *more of.*

In this sentence, *more* is an *indefinite pronoun* serving as the object of the verb *earn*:

> I earn a lot more than my sister does.

Here, "a lot" is also not an adverb but a *determinative phrase* (DP) that modifies the indefinite pronoun *more* in the comparative phrase *more than.*

Comment: a lot replaces much or more in English: a lot of money, much money// a lot of apples, many apples. In that sense, a lot of money is actually adjectival.